# Can't access vector_normal in Blender 2.93.1 geometry nodes. Is it gone

Tags: geometry-nodes

I don't see vector_normal in attribute math.  It is gone, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It was renamed. Search for "normal".

[image]